# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'ObjectId' and 'int'

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

While uploading/updating column in `mongodb`:

`persona.update_many({u"_id":(result["_id"])},{"$set": {column_name:df1.iloc[:,m][(list(result.values())[1])-1]}})`

I am getting this error:

`unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'ObjectId' and 'int'`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

from bson import ObjectId

```
persona.update_many({"_id":ObjectId(result["_id"])},{"$set": {column_name:df1.iloc[:,m][(list(result.values())1)-1]}})
```

insert ObjectId it will solve the problem